# Software update not working

Tags: ios

I Want to update my software on my iPod but it says that my iPod is up to date. I already have ios 5.1.1 and I need 6.0.1 can u help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please add the model of your iPod to see if an update is available to it.

Comment: Have you tried to connect it to your Mac/PC and tried to update it via iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

## You cannot update your iPod.

Obsolete models have a maximum iOS version that is supported by Apple, and your iPod's max version is 5.1.1. I'm guessing you have a 3rd generation iPod. As iOS evolved, devices didn't, so either the device would need to run slower or the device would have to be dropped.

#### A more technical reason:

Let's look at the specs of the 3rd generation iPod compared to the iPhone 3GS (which stopped support at iOS 6.1.3)...

iPhone 3GS specs:<sup>[(source)](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_3gs-2826.php)</sup>

> CPU: 600 MHz Cortex A8
> GPU: PowerVR SGX535
> RAM: 256 MB
> Camera: **3.1 MP stills, VGA video recording @ 30 fps**

iPod 3rd generation specs:<sup>[(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch)</sup>

> CPU: 600 MHz Cortex A8
> GPU: PowerVR SGX535
> RAM: 256 MB
> Camera: **none**

Did you notice that there is the same amount of power in the bodies of both of the devices, but the only difference was, the iPod had no camera? At that time, they were perfecting the camera on the lock screen.

In iOS 5, the arrow would actually be just a bit shorter, to accommodate for the camera shortcut. In iOS 5.1, this was replaced by the pull-up window that still only appeared on a double-tap of the home button.

In iOS 6, **the pull-up for the camera window was always there.** This meant another complete redesign of the lock screen's slider, and Apple didn't want to make an alternative UI for the iPod 3rd generation. Those that had the iPhone 3GS, they enjoyed several lag issues and battery drain issues, even though it really introduced nothing new into the OS.

#### A more realistic reason:

Apple wants people to buy their products so they can continue to generate profit. If iPhones lasted forever, the profits wouldn't be flowing in. Why do you think carriers offer upgrades?

In my experience, Apple deliberately slows performance of devices as they get older, and then people have to run out and spend close to $200 on an upgraded model of the same device.

Why else do you think people want the brand new iPhone? :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your iPod might be too old to have the newest update, which is why it says it is up to date. As Sebastian said, have you tried to update it via iTunes?